Google OAuth2 - asks permissions again in consent screen when prompt=select_account
I have got a Google project with authoriaztion code flow. A frontend redirects a user to the Google's URL(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth) for authentication and getting codeToken, which later will be sent to a backend server (the last one gets accessToken and refreshToken using a passed codeToken)
When a user's browser's profile has got ONLY one google account - frontend app redirects to Google's auth URL with prompt=none. If a user has already authenticated in my app and give all permissions - a consent screen doesn't apear again. But when a user's browser's profle has got MORE THAN ONE google accoount - frontend app redirects to Google's auth URL with prompt=select_account. If a user has already authenticated in my app a consent screen appears, a user select account and after it a user again gives permission to the app. I spent 4 days to solve it, but can't force Google only to asks which account to use without asking again permission. Maybe, it's correct behavior, but I didn't find it in docs.
A case, when user has got more than one google account in browser's profile.
Select account
Asks permission again
Force Google only to asks which account to use without asking again permission, when they were granted before.

You may want to experience with different values on the login_hint parameter and/or the prompt parameter.
